# setTimeout in discord.py?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, discord.py, settimeout

I have this code and i want it too work like a setTimeout function in discord.js but i dont know how. I want this code to show a slot machine in the embed and every time it spins, the second message edits itself for every letter it spins. I have these reference codes:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/948236057097416766/954472309748555896/unknown.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/948236057097416766/954472151866564678/unknown.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/948236057097416766/954472868790546462/unknown.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/948236057097416766/954472868790546462/unknown.png
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/948236057097416766/954473890883715092/unknown.png

from a friend and he uses .js This is my code for slots:

```
#slots 
@client.command()
async def slot(ctx,amount = None):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  if amount == None:
    em = discord.Embed(title='ERROR:', description='Please specify a amount you want to put in the slot!', color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed = em) 
    return

  bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)

  amount = int(amount)
  if amount>bal[0]:
    em = discord.Embed(title='ERROR:', description="You don't have enough money!", color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed = em) 
    return
  if amount<10:
    em = discord.Embed(title='ERROR:', description="Put a amount of ``10-70`` in the slot machine!", color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed = em) 
    return
  if amount>70:
    em = discord.Embed(title='ERROR:', description="Put a amount of ``10-70`` in the slot machine!", color=0xff0000)
    await ctx.send(embed = em) 
    return

  final = []
  for i in range(3):
      a = random.choice([':regional_indicator_x:',':regional_indicator_o:',':regional_indicator_q:',':regional_indicator_g:',':regional_indicator_u:'])
    
      final.append(a)
  em3 = discord.Embed(title='Slot:', description=f'{final}', color=0xff000)
  em3 = set.Image('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/844618714439483435/954485256021508156/ezgif.com-gif-maker.gif')
  await ctx.send(embed = em3)
```

as you can see on the last line i try to add that slots GIF. But i want it to spin 3 times and then the messages under it changes with it...  I tried to clarify my goal with this a good as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python equivalent to JavaScript's `setTimeout` function is [`time.sleep`](https://realpython.com/python-sleep/).

An example usage of `time.sleep` is:

```py
await ctx.send(embed = em)
sleep(200)
await ctx.send(embed = em3)
```

Comment: Alright, ill try!

Comment: It didnt work, i doesnt react on the .slot command anymore...

Comment: Please don't use `time.sleep` in asynchronous functions, it blocks (i.e. no other code will be run for 200 seconds in the above example). Use `asyncio.sleep` instead. Anyhow, this question is a duplicate, and should be flagged as such instead of answered.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs Sorry, its one 9f my first questions on stack... what do you mean with duplicate. Thanks for the answer tho!